# AngularForEach for inner array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm starting to learn `AngularJS` and have been struggling to use `angular.forEach`... I have an object that I fetch from my `REST API`...

I want to loop through an inner array, check for an attribute and if that attribute is `true` get a second attribute from the item.

This is the array;

```
orderItem:  { 
    id: 159
    name: Empanadas (Choice of 2)
    description: Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella
    price: 700
    available: 1
    created_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
    updated_at: 2016-01-31 16:50:31
    menu_category_id: 41
    restaurant_id: 11
    menu_modifier_groups: 
        [  { 
            id: 9
            name: Choose 2 Empanadas
            instruction: null
            min_selection_points: 2
            max_selection_points: 2
            force_selection: 1
            created_at: 2016-02-01 01:03:35
            updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:12:23
            menu_item_id: 159
            restaurant_id: 11
                menu_modifier_items: 
                [  { 
                    id: 34
                    name: Diced Beef
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:08
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:08
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: false
                 } ,  { 
                    id: 35
                    name: Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:37
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:04:37
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: true
                 } ,  { 
                    id: 36
                    name: Stilton, Spinach and Onion
                    price: 0
                    created_at: 2016-02-01 01:05:05
                    updated_at: 2016-02-01 01:05:05
                    menu_modifier_group_id: 9
                    restaurant_id: 11
                    menu_item_id: 159
                    selected: false
             }  ]
         }  ]
 }
```

What I want to do is find all `menu_modifier_items` that have `selected` = `true` get the `price` for each add them up together and finally add them to the `price` of `orderItem`.

`all menu_modifier_items price + orderItem price`

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function(orderItem) {
    angular.forEach(orderItem, function(){
    });
}
```

Any help/guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function(orderItem) {
   var total = 0;

   // for each menu_modifier_group
   angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups, function(group) {

      // for each menu_modifier_item inside of the current menu_modifier_group
      angular.forEach(group.menu_modifier_items, function(item) {

         // if the item is selected, add it's price to the total
         if (item.selected)
            total += item.price;
   });

   orderItem.price += total; // add the calculated total to the existing orderItem.price
};
```

Comment: `OrderItem > menu_modifier_groups > menu_modifier_items` thats how the arrays are nested

Comment: How can I add `total` to `orderItem.price` to get a `grantTotal`?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly an answer to your question, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on other answers (sorry if this isn't how that is supposed to work).

It's great to learn Angular, but I think it is good know that this can be done a few ways with just built in JavaScript functions as well for added context. `forEach` is a built in function of arrays, so instead of:

```
angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_items, function(val) {...})
```

you could also do:

```
orderItem.menu_modifier_items.forEach(function(val) {...})
```

If you wanted to get really JavaScripty there are other built in functions that could do the same thing in a more functional style by filtering out the array values you don't want and then combining the remaining array values into a single value:

```
var totalModifierAddOnsPrice = orderItem.menu_modifier_items.filter(function(group) {
    return group.selected; // throws out groups that are not selected
})
.reduce(function(itemA, itemB) {
    return itemA.price + itemB.price; // adds the prices together into 1 value
});
```

MDN has some really good documentation on this stuff - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray

That said, using the angular forEach function is great, and the other answers work, this is more of just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.calculatePrice = function(orderItem) {
var tot = orderItem.price;
angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups[0].menu_modifier_items,function(item,index){
    if(item.selected == true) {
        tot+=item.price;
    }
    if(index == orderItem.menu_modifier_groups[0].menu_modifier_items.length-1) {
        console.log(tot); //total price
    }
});
```

}

Comment: here tot is grant total (ie.,total + orderItem.price)

Comment: In your code, `menu_modifier_groups[0]` this means that you are getting the first array, but what if `orderItem` has many `menu_modifier_groups`? In the case where I have `menu_modifier_groups[0]`, `menu_modifier_groups[1]` etc... Can you please update your code.. thanks